# How to prove that $I +uu^T $ is a symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A = I + uu^T$ where $A$ is an $n\times n $ matrix. How can I prove that $A$ is symmetric positive definite.

Comment: Have you tried applying the definiton <v,Av>?

Answer (score 2):

Just by definition. $A$ is clearly symmetric and for all $x\ne0$ we have

$$x^T Ax=\Vert x\Vert^2+x^Tuu^Tx=\Vert x\Vert^2+\langle u,x\rangle^2>0$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
(uu^T)^T=uu^T
$$
and adding $1$ to the diagonal of a matrix doesn't affect its symmetry. Hence $I+uu^T$ is symmetric. Next for all $v\ne 0$ we have that
$$
v^T(I+uu^T)v=v^Tv+(u^Tv)^2>0.
$$